# jQuery - performance accessing elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, performance

I am making fairly heavy use of jquery ui and jqgrid in the application I am working on.  In most examples I see, these controls are accessed using the jquery selector to find the element by
 `id: $("#elementid")`.

My question is, does jquery provide good enough performance to do this over and over or is it better practice to save references to the elements when they are first accessed: 
`var elementName = $("#elementid");`

and reuse the reference instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery for ID is the same as getElementById() in Javascript.

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716266/javascript-document-getelementbyid-slow-performance) using a direct reference is faster than searching every time in the DOM tree to get your object.

> IE8 getElementById: 0.4844 ms
> , IE8 id array lookup: 0.0062 ms
>
> Chrome getElementById: 0.0039 ms
> , Chrome id array lookup: 0.0006 ms

These are the result for 10 000 get. To see the whole code for the benchmark click the link.

Comment: half a millisecond for 10.000 lookups doesn’t count as performance gain in my world, but that decision is entirely up to the author :)

Comment: Well it is mathematically. What you do with number is personal I think ;)

Comment: I would seem that for my purposes it's not a big deal and it saves me from littering my code with global variables to reference some of the elements.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

actually Jquery best practice is caching references. diving into to DOM each time is costly and as we learned (from one of SO founders) [performance is a feature](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/performance-is-a-feature.html). you can look into a variery of jQuery best practice in [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/#chapter-9)

Answer (score 0):

Defining and reusing a variable is probably slightly faster and might be considered "best practice", but `$('#id')` maps to the native `Element.getElementById` which is definitely *fast enough* for most applications. Even if you did tests on thousands of lookups, you wouldn’t get noticeable differences for the human mind.

I’d say it’s a matter of coding style in the end.